# mod-mysql-postgresql tries to download io.vertx~lang-scala~1.0.0 module during startup

Tags: java, scala, vert.x

I am using mod-mysql-postgresql module as part of my project. During startup I notice that mod-mysql-postgresql tries to download io.vertx~lang-scala~1.0.0 . I get the following line in the startup message

INFO: Downloading io.vertx~lang-scala~1.0.0. Please wait...

I am not sure from where io.vertx~lang-scala~1.0.0 line is coming. If I include io.vertx~lang-scala~1.0.0 in mod.json "includes" section, then I don't get this error. But then the application fails with following error

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/vertx/java/platform/impl/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/vertx/scala/core/VertxAccess"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleClassLoader.doLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:136)
at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleClassLoader.loadFromModule(ModuleClassLoader.java:121)
at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:108)
```

**Environment Details:**

Vertx version: 2.1.5
mod-mysql-postgresql version: 0.3.1

**Scala entry in vertx/conf/langs.properties**
scala=io.vertx~lang-scala_2.10~1.1.0-M1:org.vertx.scala.platform.impl.ScalaVerticleFactory

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in mod-mysql-postgresql. Vertx fatjar tries to use default io.vertx~lang-scala~1.0.0 mod for scala files. To override the default setting, I added langs.properties in src/main/resources/platform_lib with following lines

> scala=io.vertx~lang-scala_2.10~1.1.0-M1:org.vertx.scala.platform.impl.ScalaVerticleFactory
>   .scala=scala

And added io.vertx~lang-scala_2.10~1.1.0-M1 in mod.json

> {
>     "main":"Main",
>     "auto-redeploy": true,
>     "includes":"io.vertx~lang-scala_2.10~1.1.0-M1",
>   }